# Program that runs in every pc

Tags: c#

I created a c# application whose target .net framework is 4.5.1. it is deployed but not working on other pc. After searching the reason I found the problem is. net framework incompatibility.

If a pc doesn't have. NET framework 4.5.1 can't run my application.

There is also a solution with visual studio's deployment option. It automatically downloads if .net framework isn't installed. But it requires Internet and I don't want to make users to download from internet for this small application and to make this app as much offline as can be.

I also created an install file with innosetup 5.5.9. but it just create a install file, not solves the problem I faced.

so I want to deploy my program such as it runs on almost all version of. net framework. How to do so?

Comment: You could try to target lower .net framework (say, .net 2.0). That way, your program will run in almost all version of .net framework.

Comment: Note that targeting a lower .NET version will strip you of some features you are no doubt relying on in 4.5. For example, in 2.0 you have generics.. but not LINQ.

Comment: @Ian Lowering it may also require a framework to be installed. For example, SQL Server requires that .NET 3.5 be installed, even if you already have 4.0 or above.

Comment: @codran that must be few of the special cases which I miss out... But for most cases, targetting lower .net framework should help - this is more common (and the easiest) approach I think, provided that your project does not rely on special feature of higher .net.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options:

- Downgrade to the .NET version that you are sure is installed. You can see an overview [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) which .NET framework version is pre-installed on which Windows version.
- Provide the installer of the desired .NET framework with your installation. ClickOnce even has support to find the installer file next to your own setup installer.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. you would have to write your code using the lowest version of .net, and it still wouldn't run on every PC.

What you can do is to carry the installer of your .net version. Visual Studio provides an option for that;
in the project's `Properties` menu select the `Publish` tab.
Click the `Application Files...` button, select your .net version, and select:

```
"Download prerequisites from the same location as my application".
```

click `OK`.

Comment: and where should I put the instalable .net version?

Comment: Visual Studio manages that automatically if I remember well. What you have to set is the Publish Location, which means the folder where your installer will be placed by VS. Every other options should be the "most offline" one.